# MongoDB installation macOS Catalina

Tags: node.js, mongodb, terminal, macos-catalina

I recently started developing with NodeJS. In the course I attend, they gave me steps to install on Mac but it's giving me problems. After a some googling, I understood that macOS Catalina has blocked writing access to the root folder. After that, I spent a day searching on Google and Stack Overflow for solutions to this problem. There were many different solutions, but none of them worked. Some installed, but the `mongod` command wouldn't work. Even the installation process on MongoDB itself didn't work.

At the end, I decided to use MongoDB Atlas. So in my cluster0, I went to Connect > Connect with `mongo` shell > I do not have MongoDB installed. They gave some steps to install it with Homebrew. Now, when I type `mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0.hflrg.mongodb.net/<dbname>" --username <myUserName>`, it connects to MongoDB Atlas. The `mongod` command still doesn't work.

Can you tell me a way to install MongoDB on Mac. I have macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5.

Note: I don't have much experience with the terminal, so if possible, please avoid using terms like "Add so and so the you $PATH variable", and try to explain in detail. A huge thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the `mongo` command and it runs, but how doesn't it work?

Comment: Can you tell us where you stored your mongodb ? Do you know where it is located in your computer ? If you do, can you print the location ?

Comment: @Matt Sorry I meant `mongod`.

Comment: @ShyamPillai, I installed it based on [these](https://blog.londonappbrewery.com/how-to-download-install-mongodb-on-mac-2895ccd2b5c1)  instructions first. I attended Angela Yu's course. After that, I also tried installing based on MongoDB's instructions, but no use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), it uses `/usr/local` by default.

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

```
mongo --quiet --eval 'db.version()'
4.2.8
```

Answer (score 4):

I usually and like to install by downloading .tgz package from [MongoDB Community Server](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community?tck=docs_server), and setting up via command lines.

1. Download .tgz package from [MongoDB Community Server](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community?tck=docs_server).
2. Extract the files from the downloaded archive:

```
tar -zxvf mongodb-macos-*.tgz
```

3. Copy binaries in your **PATH** environment variable:

```
sudo cp /path/to/the/mongodb-directory/bin/* /usr/local/bin/
```

4. Create the data directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

```
IMPORTANT
Starting with macOS 10.15 Catalina, Apple restricts access to the MongoDB default data directory of /data/db. On macOS 10.15 Catalina, you must use a different data directory, such as /usr/local/var/mongodb.
```

5. Create the log directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/var/log/mongodb
```

6. Run MongoDB:

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

To run mongod in the background, use *--fork* at the end of command line:

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log --fork
```

Helpful links and references:

[Installing MongoDB on macOS tarball](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x-tarball/) 
[MongoDB on macOS Catalina v10.15+](https://medium.com/macoclock/setup-mongodb-on-macos-catalina-10-15-and-above-6b2c2cc676b3)

Hope these may help! Have a great one!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, but is based on the answer by @Erni_Souza

1. Download the .tgz package from here [MongoDB Community Server](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community).
2. Extract the files on your machine using `tar -zxvf mongodb-macos-*.tgz` or just use the default Archive Utility.app on your machine.
3. Copy the binaries into your `/usr/local/bin` folder with:

   `sudo cp /path/to/the/mongodb-directory/bin/* /usr/local/bin/` just as instructed or you can resort to using the `./mongod` command via Terminal.app from the folder you extracted into.
4. Create the data directory `mkdir -p ~/data/db`
5. Run mongodb

   `mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`
   or with
   `./mongod --dbpath ~/data/db`
   if the binaries are still in the directory you extracted them to.

You can check out this link [MongoDB on macOS Catalina v10.15+](https://medium.com/macoclock/setup-mongodb-on-macos-catalina-10-15-and-above-6b2c2cc676b3) as given in the answer by @Erni_Souza for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I used Homebrew, it's easier.